# Cannot resolve symbol 'menu_main'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created `menu` folder in `res`. Inside the `menu` folder I created a **menu_main.xml** file which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Since I'm using this **xml** in conjunction with a code inside `MainActivity`. It gives me an error of "Cannot resolve symbol for `menu_main`. Below is the snippet:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I cannot understand why this is happening even after creating the xml in a specified folder. Maybe I'm missing something silly but I can't get a hold of it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check which R package you're accessing, it should be <your_package>.<app_name>.R.* check the import statements for the same

Comment: Okay, will do that.

Comment: have you `clean` and `rebuild` the project. and if that not work just go to `File > Select Invalidate Caches and Restart`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: Can't you do File > New > Android Resource and select the menu option?

Comment: It's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using `android:showAsAction="never"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity"><itemandroid:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="always" ></menu>
```

try this code

Comment: Thank you, Navas!

Answer (score 2):

Clean and rebuild your project by going to `Build>Clean` Project.
Go to `File>Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of cache memory store by IDE so IDE can not identify that time you have to `Clean` and `Rebuild` the Project. And if the IDE contains lots of caches memory that time you have to clean that memory the Restart it.

That time you have to go to `File and Select Invalidate Caches and Restart`.

Comment: @Karan Thakker I posted brief answer you can accept it if that help you.

Answer (score 1):

`android:showAsAction="always"` here you go.! try to follow Proper Android Developer Documentation [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) 
and this Tutorial Will help you too.! [Menu Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example)  And Last go to file click on  Invalidate Caches and Restart.! hope this will help u.!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```